# Modifying go to use Gem5 m5ops: go tool dist shows import message then quit

Tags: go, cgo, gem5

I am pretty new to golang.

I'm trying to insert some C function calls (specifically [m5ops](https://www.gem5.org/documentation/general_docs/m5ops/)) to golang's runtime (specifically [src/proc.go](https://go.dev/src/runtime/proc.go)).

I was trying to use [cgo](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/cgo), which results in adding this import to the beginning of `proc.go`:

```golang
// #cgo CFLAGS: -I$(GEM5_PATH)/include -static
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L$(GEM5_PATH)/util/m5/build/x86/out -lm5
// #include <gem5/m5ops.h>
import "C"
```

but when I tryna rebuild, using `./all.bash`, the script output this then exited:

```
./all.bash
Building Go cmd/dist using /usr/local/go. (go1.20.5 linux/amd64)
Building Go toolchain1 using /usr/local/go.
Building Go bootstrap cmd/go (go_bootstrap) using Go toolchain1.
go tool dist: /home/landerx/goroot/src/runtime/proc.go imports C
```

A more verbose version of above output:

```
./all.bash -v
Building Go cmd/dist using /usr/local/go. (go1.20.5 linux/amd64)
cmd/dist

Building Go toolchain1 using /usr/local/go.
internal/goarch
internal/coverage/rtcov
internal/goos
internal/race
internal/unsafeheader
internal/goexperiment
unicode
runtime/internal/syscall
sync/atomic
runtime/internal/atomic
internal/cpu
unicode/utf8
internal/itoa
math/bits
internal/abi
runtime/internal/math
runtime/internal/sys
bootstrap/internal/goarch
bootstrap/internal/goexperiment
bootstrap/math/bits
encoding
bootstrap/internal/unsafeheader
bootstrap/internal/platform
bootstrap/internal/coverage
internal/bytealg
bootstrap/internal/abi
math
unicode/utf16
bootstrap/internal/goversion
internal/goversion
bootstrap/internal/race
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/test
runtime
internal/reflectlite
runtime/metrics
sync
internal/testlog
internal/godebug
bootstrap/internal/bisect
math/rand
errors
sort
bootstrap/sort
io
internal/oserror
internal/safefilepath
path
strconv
bootstrap/strconv
syscall
bootstrap/container/heap
hash
text/tabwriter
bytes
strings
hash/adler32
hash/fnv
hash/crc32
crypto
reflect
bootstrap/internal/types/errors
go/build/constraint
bootstrap/go/build/constraint
bufio
regexp/syntax
html
internal/syscall/execenv
internal/syscall/unix
time
regexp
context
io/fs
internal/poll
internal/fmtsort
bootstrap/internal/saferio
encoding/binary
os
bootstrap/cmd/internal/notsha256
encoding/base64
bootstrap/cmd/internal/sys
crypto/md5
bootstrap/internal/lazyregexp
internal/lazyregexp
path/filepath
fmt
os/exec
log
bootstrap/internal/buildcfg
flag
bootstrap/cmd/internal/src
text/scanner
bootstrap/cmd/internal/edit
bootstrap/cmd/internal/pkgpath
go/token
bootstrap/compress/flate
bootstrap/internal/zstd
go/doc/comment
bootstrap/debug/dwarf
encoding/json
runtime/debug
bootstrap/math/big
bootstrap/cmd/internal/bio
net/url
go/scanner
bootstrap/cmd/internal/objabi
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/abt
bootstrap/cmd/internal/goobj
bootstrap/cmd/internal/gcprog
bootstrap/cmd/internal/quoted
bootstrap/compress/zlib
encoding/hex
compress/flate
go/ast
internal/buildcfg
internal/goroot
bootstrap/cmd/internal/dwarf
runtime/trace
bootstrap/cmd/internal/archive
bootstrap/cmd/internal/obj
bootstrap/debug/macho
bootstrap/debug/elf
bootstrap/debug/pe
bootstrap/internal/xcoff
bootstrap/cmd/link/internal/dwtest
compress/gzip
bootstrap/internal/profile
runtime/pprof
go/doc
go/printer
go/internal/typeparams
go/parser
bootstrap/cmd/internal/codesign
bootstrap/go/constant
bootstrap/internal/pkgbits
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/syntax
bootstrap/cmd/link/internal/benchmark
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/pgo/internal/graph
go/build
go/format
bootstrap/cmd/cgo
bootstrap/cmd/internal/obj/loong64
bootstrap/cmd/internal/obj/mips
bootstrap/cmd/internal/obj/wasm
bootstrap/cmd/internal/obj/arm
bootstrap/cmd/internal/obj/arm64
bootstrap/cmd/internal/obj/s390x
bootstrap/cmd/internal/obj/riscv
bootstrap/cmd/internal/obj/ppc64
bootstrap/cmd/internal/obj/x86
bootstrap/cmd/asm/internal/flags
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/base
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/logopt
bootstrap/cmd/asm/internal/lex
bootstrap/cmd/link/internal/sym
bootstrap/cmd/link/internal/loader
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/bitvec
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/types
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/types2
bootstrap/cmd/link/internal/loadelf
bootstrap/cmd/link/internal/loadmacho
bootstrap/cmd/link/internal/loadpe
bootstrap/cmd/link/internal/loadxcoff
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/typebits
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/ir
bootstrap/cmd/asm/internal/arch
bootstrap/cmd/link/internal/ld
bootstrap/cmd/asm/internal/asm
bootstrap/cmd/asm
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/abi
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/deadcode
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/typecheck
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/objw
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/staticdata
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/compare
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/pgo
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/coverage
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/loopvar
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/importer
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/escape
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/inline
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/reflectdata
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/devirtualize
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/staticinit
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/ssa
bootstrap/cmd/link/internal/amd64
bootstrap/cmd/link/internal/loong64
bootstrap/cmd/link/internal/arm
bootstrap/cmd/link/internal/mips
bootstrap/cmd/link/internal/mips64
bootstrap/cmd/link/internal/arm64
bootstrap/cmd/link/internal/ppc64
bootstrap/cmd/link/internal/riscv64
bootstrap/cmd/link/internal/s390x
bootstrap/cmd/link/internal/wasm
bootstrap/cmd/link/internal/x86
bootstrap/cmd/link
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/liveness
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/ssagen
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/amd64
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/arm
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/arm64
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/dwarfgen
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/loong64
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/mips
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/mips64
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/wasm
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/s390x
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/riscv64
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/ppc64
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/walk
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/x86
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/noder
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/pkginit
bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/gc
bootstrap/cmd/compile

Building Go bootstrap cmd/go (go_bootstrap) using Go toolchain1.
runtime
go tool dist: /home/landerx/goroot/src/runtime/proc.go imports C
```

Tried the `CGO_ENABLED=1` flag, seemingly didn't make any difference.

Tried running only `make.bash`, seemingly didn't make any difference.

I wonder if it is a dependency problem, but didn't see any related message to the pseudo-package `cgo`, didn't see any error from my vscode either.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Ok... Finally, let me myself answer this.

## Why it doesn't work

After some investigation, I found that seemingly Go (tool dist) doesn't allow importing cgo (`import "C"`) in most of the go inner source files ([link](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/08e35cc3347f97ef750fd21fbef1061b043580e4/src/cmd/dist/build.go#L835C19-L835C19))

## Workarounds

Still there are some workarounds to achieve the effect, which is to **use m5ops in go**.

### 1. Pass function pointers through global vars

U can define global function pointers in `proc.go`, and in ur go application, import cgo, and assign those global function pointers with ur functions that do m5ops. [Calling C function pointers is not supported](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/cgo#hdr-Passing_pointers:%7E:text=Calling%20C%20function%20pointers%20is%20currently%20not%20supported), so u need to wrap it with a golang function.

### 2. Go Asm

Go uses a lot Go Asm in its inner source files, to handle stack switch, etc.

On the other hand m5ops will at the end be inlined as a single pseudo-instruction.

So following Go Asm's syntax and function binding, which happens in [asm_amd64.s](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s) and [stubs.go](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/stubs.go), it is feasible to write an asm function that includes the m5ops instruction, then call it wherever in ur `runtime.go` should be good.

## Other info

- It seems that in `runtime.go`, when it switch to system stack, it can no longer execute function outside of the file(or the package?), so method 1 won't work if u try to insert those function calls into code which will run on system stack. So I finally discovered the second method.